# Snappy timezone

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-core, timezone

I read [the snappy config command](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/config-command/), but I still can't change timezone. The example doesn't looks like a terminal command!

Can you help me to set my snappy timezone?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `snappy` command. The timezone is a property of the OS, which in Ubuntu Core is called `ubuntu-core` and this snappy part is managed by `snappy` itself.

To read the current configuration for a part just run

```
snappy config [snap part]
```

And to apply one run

```
snappy config [snap part] [config]
```

To particularly change the timezone (to America/Cordoba in this example)

```
CONFIG=/tmp/core_config

snappy config ubuntu-core > "$CONFIG"
sed -i 's/timezone: .*$/timezone: America/Cordoba/' > "$CONFIG"
sudo snappy config ubuntu-core "$CONFIG"
```

> Take note that due to a bug in the `snappy` command itself, this can't be piped in one single statement which is why I show it in three lines.

Answer (score 1):

the way it's done now is:

`sudo timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>`

you can get your timezone string for timedatectl with timedatectl:

`timedatectl list-timezones`

source: ogra's (contributor to Core) reply [reply](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-configure-timezone-and-nameserver-on-ubuntu-core/2160/4) on the snapcraft forum.

Answer (score 0):

sergiusens answer have few errors, example should look like this:

```
CONFIG=/tmp/core_config

snappy config ubuntu-core > "$CONFIG"
sed -i 's/timezone: .*$/timezone: America\/Cordoba/' "$CONFIG"
sudo snappy config ubuntu-core "$CONFIG"
```

Forward slash before "Cordoba" need to be escaped and do not use write symbol ">"