# Ubuntu Core 16 - How to change time zone persistent?

Tags: ubuntu-core, time, persistence, timezone

to set the time zone I tried following:

```
auser@localhost:~$ sudo timedatectl
      Local time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:46:14 UTC
  Universal time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:46:14 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:46:13
       Time zone: n/a (UTC, +0000)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
auser@localhost:~$ sudo timedatectl set-ntp 0
auser@localhost:~$ sudo timedatectl
      Local time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:46:34 UTC
  Universal time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:46:34 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:46:33
       Time zone: n/a (UTC, +0000)
 Network time on: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
auser@localhost:~$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin
auser@localhost:~$ sudo timedatectl
      Local time: Fri 2019-05-17 08:46:56 CEST
  Universal time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:46:56 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:46:55
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
 Network time on: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Everything looks great but then reboot ...

```
auser@localhost:~$ sudo reboot
auser@localhost:~$ sudo timedatectl
      Local time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:48:51 UTC
  Universal time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:48:51 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2019-05-17 06:48:51
       Time zone: n/a (UTC, +0000)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

NTP synchronized switched to yes and Local time and Time zone switched back to UTC. How can I change these so that it survives a reboot?

Comment: Have you get a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/641186/snappy-timezone ?

Comment: yes I saw this but it says `command not found` if I type `snappy`

Comment: Do `sudo apt install ubuntu-snappy-cli`

Comment: `Ubuntu Core does not use apt-get, see 'snap --help'!`

Answer (score 0):

Do in order to install snappy:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-snappy-cli
```

In order oo read the current configuration for ubuntu-core:

```
snappy config ubuntu-core
```

Then in order to update it:

```
CONFIG=/tmp/core_config

snappy config ubuntu-core > "$CONFIG"
sed -i 's/timezone: .*$/timezone: America\/Cordoba/' "$CONFIG"
sudo snappy config ubuntu-core "$CONFIG"
```

as mentionned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641186/snappy-timezone).

Comment: can't use apt:
`auser@localhost:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-snappy-cli`
`Ubuntu Core does not use apt-get, see 'snap --help'!`

Comment: try `snap find ubuntu-core`

Comment: it finds: `ubuntu-core` `ubuntu-core-slides` `snappy-debug` `fswebcam` `demo-wget` and `mysql-experimental`